# Using Interview Follow-Up to Highlight Skills

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I recently had a job interview for a software developer position at a local company.  It's been about a week and the interviewer just e-mailed me today and mentioned that he thought I interviewed well.  He also told me that I was the first person they interviewed and they wanted to interview other candidates to compare and contrast.  That seems reasonable.

After the interview, I felt that I came across a little weak in one particular area (the only experience I could come up with was something that wasn't very challenging).  It's then that I realized that I had forgotten to mention a couple projects that I had completed.  I've been regretting that omission, and looking for a way to let the interviewer know about said projects.

That brings me to my question.  Should I use this follow-up e-mail from the interviewer as an invitation to mention those projects in a response?  Or, should I speak more generally and let him know there's some experience I forgot to highlight out of nervousness (which is true by the way)?  Should I not bring it up at all?

P.S. If someone can come up with a better title, then please change mine.  I'm not the best when it comes to those.

Comment: I think that trying to continue talking about your virtues after the interview comes off as needy. You should interview at more places and build your overall interview skills, so this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you interviewed well initially despite being weak in one particular area, I wouldn't bring up the additional projects that you completed.  Instead I would include a link to your **online portfolio** or other **professional network account** which contains information about those projects.

This way you don't seem desperate and at the same time, if they are really interested they can see the additional projects that you have completed and failed to mention during the first interview.

Comment: I like this suggestion.  Perfect reasoning in that last paragraph.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is the value for the interviewer in knowing that you did these other projects at this point? I can see this being similar to the person that gets a couple of questions wrong on the exam and then wants to tell the teacher, "I know this after all. Here are the answers..." which does very little for the teacher as the test is over and things have moved forward.

I'd suggest letting this go for this company and remember for future interviews. Otherwise you may come across as the developer that can't let things go which can be a rather unattractive quality as there may be bugs that won't get fixed and other issues that you have to remember your priorities in the job.

Comment: I like the analogy to the exam.  Good point on coming across as one who can't let go.

Comment: What about coming out as a person who really wants the job?

Comment: @Pithikos, how does sending a follow-up about one's history and corrections in the interview demonstrate a desire for the job though? I'd likely suspect there are other ways to show one wants the job and chances are that other candidates may also really want the job.

Comment: @JBKing well I would interpret it as the person actually cares about how he did in the interview and thus cares more about getting the job than others that just let it go.

Comment: @Pithikos, that answer doesn't explain anything you do realize right? Poor communication doesn't help here.